# What does the dark background mean in Chrome's device emulator?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If I open [flickr.com](https://www.flickr.com) and open Chrome's device emulator (or responsive view), I can drag and drop the right boundary to make the viewport smaller. If I drag it to the left, it leaves behind a dark grey background, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Flickr in Chrome's device emulator]

I've tried it in other websites, and it doesn't always appear. It doesn't seem to represent `<html>` or `<body>`'s size, but I would like to know what it *does* mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just showing "Hey, content exists off-canvas." In other words, if you scroll more content is there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Garbee, but it is more important to know when it happens.

If there is no viewport meta tag with width=device-width, then the browser will try to reescale the page to fit, but sometimes may be too big.

The other possibility is that the viewport meta tag is there but the withs are not 100% and may be wider than the actual width of your phone.

This may seem similar but are very different situations you must take into account.

Comment: "then the browser will try to rescale the page to fit" you're talking about mobile browsers only, right?

Comment: Yes, as this feature is ment to test for tablets and phones and reescales the page not like the desktop browser would usually do but as the mobile browsers.

Comment: To be clear, it happens *ANYTIME* content is off canvas. Even normal  page content when scrolling counts. Nothing to do with meta viewport or anything. Also, with DM V2 it is going away, so no longer a problem once that lands.